# How to validate raw CSRF data in CodeIgniter4?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, csrf, codeigniter-4

#### CSRF data generator

```js
var data = {
    token: <?php echo csrf_token(); ?>,
    hash: <?php echo csrf_hash(); ?>
};

// The `data` object will be sent as POST data to `example.com/recipient` via jQuery AJAX
```

#### CSRF data validator

```php
<?php
$is_valid = method_or_function_for_csrf_validation( $_POST['token'], $_POST['hash'] );

// Of course, the `method_or_function_for_csrf_validation()` function is just fiction
?>
```

The `method_or_function_for_csrf_validation()` function is just fictional and non-existing. I don't know how to compose the validator for the CSRF data. Is there a function something like that?

How to validate those raw CSRF data in CodeIgniter4?

Comment: I think you'll need to dig into system\core\Security.php, there is a function csrf_verify(), around line 208

Comment: earlier comment was for CI 3.x, in CI 4.x the function is called CSRFVerify

Answer (score 0):

for codeigniter4.0.4 if you put
csrf_field()

into a form and you have implemented form helper helper('form') in controller then you can confirm the value of say a CSRF token in the controller, that the form is posting to using:

echo $this->request->getVar(csrf_token());

now as i understand it the Class Security Class method is  called automatically to check:

public function CSRFVerify(RequestInterface $request)

{}

Security.php is located /var/www/htdocs/appstarter/system/Security/Security.php on my apache

Answer (score 0):

Probably im a little bit late,but it can also help other people.
You can activate the global csrf verification as it is written on the [official documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html)

If you want to **manualy** verify the csrf token you can create a file helper in the `Helpers` folder, like `security_helper.php` and put this into the file:

```
<?php
    function verifyCsrf(){
        $request = \Config\Services::request();
        $security = \Config\Services::security();
    
        try
        {
                $security->CSRFVerify($request);
        }
        catch (SecurityException $e)
        {
                if (config('App')->CSRFRedirect && ! $request->isAJAX())
                {
                        return redirect()->back()->with('error', $e->getMessage());
                }
    
                throw $e;
        }
    }
    function setCsrf(){
        $request = \Config\Services::request();
        $security = \Config\Services::security();
        $security->CSRFSetCookie($request);
    }
```

In the controller function where you want to generate the csrf, just load the helper and call the function, like this:

```
helper('security')
setCsrf();
```

In the controller function where you want verify the csrf load the helper and call the function like this:

```
helper('security')
verifyCsrf();
```